# Can't complete OS X 10.10.5 software update in App Store

Tags: macos, software-update

I'm trying to update my iMac to OS X 10.10.5, but there seems to be an error when updating.

When I press the update button a message appears to download and restart. When I press it the update starts to install. After some time it get blocked or a message 'show details' is shown, but even after pressing it nothing happens. The update still remains in the App Store.

How can I complete the update?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are already on 10.10.*something* just get the Combo Updater directly from Apple, rather than from the App Store.

Direct link: [Download OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832)

Comment: Hmm I recommend to first boot to Recovery HD and check the main volume for errors (and repair them if needed) and then update with the Combo installer.

Comment: Very sensible suggestion - I was just going for *easy* rather than *thorough* as a start point, as we're not really sure what the error was, or indeed what the current OS is.